# WifiRttManager - No virtual method startRanging

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, indoor-positioning-system, android-9.0-pie

I been testing the preview of Android P and I'm having some problems with the WifiRttManager used for indoorPositioning. For some reason when I try to use the method startRanging from WifiRttManager but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method startRanging(Landroid/net/wifi/rtt/RangingRequest;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;Landroid/net/wifi/rtt/RangingResultCallback;)V in class Landroid/net/wifi/rtt/WifiRttManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.net.wifi.rtt.WifiRttManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

The method displayed by the android studio is the following:

`startRanging(RangingRequest rangingRequest, Executor executor, RangingResultCallback callback);`

but the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/rtt/WifiRttManager.html has this other one:

`startRanging(RangingRequest request, RangingResultCallback callback, Handler handler)`

Could you help me to check what's happening please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problems.
Updating the Android P to revision 2 using SDK Manager in Android Studio will fix this problem.

Comment: It seems that was a bug related to the first release, now I'm having problems understanding how the WifiManager works now because there are a lot of methods deprecated.